# useEffect does not fire redux action until page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

my useEffect function does not fire the redux action call on first page load, I just get an error which says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` which is probably because the state has not loaded because the action was never fired I guess. But when I reload the page it just works fine and the components also load without any problems.

here's my react component:

```
const BooksById = ({bookdetails:{bookDetails,loading},getBookById,match}) =>{
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("action fired")
        getBookById(match.params.genre)
    },[getBookById,match.params.genre])

const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);
  
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    status: '',
    rating: '',
    review: ''
});
const {status, rating, review} = formData;

const onChange = e => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})

const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
   console.log(status, rating, review);
};
return (
(
    <Fragment>
    {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
    <Fragment>
            <Container style={{paddingTop: "1.5rem"}}>
                <Card>
                    <Row>
                        <aside className="col-sm-3 border-right">
                            <article className="gallery-wrap"> 
                                <div className="img-wrap">
                                <center>
                                    <Media src="https://via.placeholder.com/190x320"/>
                                </center>
                                </div>
                                <center>
                                    <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle}><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Add to shelf </Button>
                                    <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
                                        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Add to shelf</ModalHeader>
                                        <ModalBody>
                                            <Form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
                                                <FormGroup row>
                                                <Label for="exampleSelect" sm={2}>Status</Label>
                                                    <Col sm={6}>
                                                        <Input type="select" name="Add to" id="exampleSelect" placeholder="* select a shelf" value={status} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required>
                                                            <option value=''></option>
                                                            <option value='plan to read'>plan to read</option>
                                                            <option value='reading'>reading</option>
                                                            <option value='completed'>completed</option>
                                                            <option value='dropped'>dropped</option>
                                                        </Input>
                                                    </Col>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                                <FormGroup row>
                                                <Label for="exampleSelect" sm={2}>Rating</Label>
                                                    <Col sm={4}>
                                                        <Input type="select" name="rating" placeholder="(optional)" id="exampleSelect"  value={rating} onChange={e => onChange(e)}>
                                                            <option value =''>(optional)</option>
                                                            <option value ='1'>1</option>
                                                            <option value ='2'>2</option>
                                                            <option value ='3'>3</option>
                                                            <option value ='4'>4</option>
                                                            <option value ='5'>5</option>
                                                        </Input>
                                                    </Col>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                                <FormGroup row>
                                                    <Label for="exampleText" sm={2}>Review</Label>
                                                    <Col sm={9}>
                                                        <Input type="textarea" name="review" placeholder="(optional)" id="exampleText" value={review} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
                                                    </Col>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                                <Button type ="submit" color="primary" >save</Button>{' '}
                                                <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                                            </Form>                                             
                                        </ModalBody>
                                        
                                    </Modal>
                                </center>
                            </article> 
                        </aside>
                        <aside class="col-sm-7">
                            <article class="card-body p-5">
                                    <h3 class="title mb-3">{bookDetails.bookName}</h3>
                                    <dl class="param param-feature">
                                        <dt>Rating</dt>
                                        <dd>
                                            <span class="float-center"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star"></i></span>
                                            <span class="float-center"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star"></i></span>
                                            <span class="float-center"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star"></i></span>
                                            {' '}3.05
                                        </dd>
                                    </dl>
                                    <dl class="item-property">
                                        <dt>Description</dt>
                                        <dd><p>{bookDetails.bookDescription}</p></dd>
                                    </dl>
                                    <dl class="param param-feature">
                                        <dt>Author</dt>
                                        <dd>someone</dd>
                                    </dl>  
                                    <dl class="param param-feature">
                                        <dt>Publish date</dt>
                                        <dd>some date</dd>
                                    </dl>  
                                    <dl class="param param-feature">
                                        <dt>Genres</dt>
                                        <dd>{
                                            bookDetails.bookGenre.map(x=>x + ', ')}</dd>
                                    </dl>  
                            </article> 
                        </aside> 
                    </Row>
                </Card>
            </Container>
            {/* review container */}
            <Container style={{paddingTop: "1.5rem",paddingBottom: "1.5rem"}}>
            <hr/>
            <h2 style={{paddingTop: "1.5rem",paddingBottom: "1.5rem"}}>Reviews</h2>
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md="12">
                            <p>
                                <strong>some one</strong>
                                <span class="float-right"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span class="float-right"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span class="float-right"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star"></i></span>
                            </p>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the pr make  but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </Container>
    </Fragment> )}
</Fragment>
)
)

BooksById.propTypes={
    bookdetails: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getBookById: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    bookdetails: state.bookdetails
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getBookById}) (BooksById);
```

here's is the action I am calling:

```
export const getBookById = (id) => dispatch => {
    axios.get(`/api/booksDetails/${id}`)
         .then(res=>{
             dispatch({
                 type: GET_BOOKBYID,
                 payload: res.data
             })
         })
         .catch(err=>{
            dispatch({
                type: BOOKDETAILS_FAIL,
                payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
            })
        })
}
```

and here is the reducer:

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;
  
    switch (type) {
        case GET_BOOKDETAILS:
        case GET_BOOKBYGENRE:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                bookDetails: payload
            }
        case GET_BOOKBYID:
                return{
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    bookDetails: payload
                }
        case BOOKDETAILS_FAIL:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                bookDetails: payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

please help me with what should I change, Thankyou.

Comment: The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` yet there is no code you posted that tries to get `length` from anything. Maybe try to set bookDetails of initial state to an array or use `loading` correctly before getting bookDetails.length (I guess that's what you're trying to do but code is missing). Normally you'd check redux dev tools and see if the correct actions are dispatched with the correct values and if they cause the correct changes.

Comment: @HMR i have uploaded the code now, actually the file is too huge that's why I didn't upload it, also I am using redux devtools and the action does not fire at all until I have reloaded the page, also I have added a spinner if loading is false, but it's still not working

Comment: Still not seeing the line that causes the error. Redux devtools should show you the state when init action is dispatched so you can make sure loading is set correctly and you didn't map loading to props in connect.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to use react redux hooks much more simple
[for the documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

first I recommend you to take all the action and put it in one file instead of do this

```
 dispatch({
                 type: GET_BOOKBYID,
                 payload: res.data
             })
```

because it will make you life much more easy and can see if something went wrong who use this function and where
About your question I think in the connect params you need to pass it like this :

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onUpdate: (employee) => dispatch(actionTypes.UpdateEmployeeFetch(employee))
    }
}
```

as I remember you need to pass it like this or nothing will happens (this happens to me too!)
if you decide to use the hook version you can do it like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const addToFavorite = useCallback(
    (key) => dispatch(actionCreators.addExistedCity(key)),
    [dispatch]
)
```